# How should we put custom UIButton in google maps app?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uibutton

By clicking on a button am navigating to google maps app, and there am showing directions from one location to another location.
here is the code which i wrote in button

```
@IBAction func movetonextclass() {
     if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!) {
        let googleMapUrlString: String = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(CDouble(startLat)),\(CDouble(startLong))&mode=driving"
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: googleMapUrlString)!)
    }
    else {
        let googleMapUrlString: String = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d,&daddr=\(CDouble(stopLat)),\(CDouble(stopLong))"
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: googleMapUrlString)!)
    }            
}
```

now i would like to display a custom UIButton in that screen.

if i click on that button, i should navigate to my own app
how should i put a button in google maps screen?
could any one help me with this

Comment: inside the app you can do this, outside you can't

Comment: You can not add or modify other app but you can use same functionality in your app it self.

Comment: @CodeChanger can we show directions(it should be like turn by turn) between two locations  in our app ?
if yes could you show me how please. i'll be thankful to you

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add anything in not your application, but actually from ios 9, when you open an another app when your app in active state you can back to previous application by tapping at the top left corner.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Where's your code to do this? How about a detailed explanation on how this works? (Personally, I've *yet* to see how in *any* iOS app you can open a second app and see this sort of UI you describe. Flagged.